# Regex to match X, Y, or XY but not an empty string

Tags: java, regex

I am writing Java regex patterns and have run into a situation where I expect X or X or both but no null.
So the following regex pattern works fine for this.

(X)|(Y)|(XY)

But the problem is that X and Y can be quite long and I have to write a lot of this kind, which means a lot of redundancy and maintenance headache.

(X)?(Y)? doesn't work because it can match null which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but you can use a negative lookahead to avoid a blank match?

```
^(?!^$)(X)?(Y)?$
```

The negative lookahead `(?!`..`)` succeeds if its contents does *not* match at that position, so in this instance the whole pattern only succeeds if X or Y or both match, otherwise the `^$` is matched so the lookahead fails.

It assumes this is the entirety of the match - for use in part of a larger pattern the same concept can be used if there are appropriate anchors for determining what a failure to match would be.

Otherwise, as others have already suggested, creating X and Y as strings and building the pattern from those will avoid the redundancy.

Comment: nhahtdh, the intent is to not match empty string, no? If they did then the question being asked wouldn't make sense? (At the very least, the `?` quantifier would be redundant.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this using (just) regexes.

My suggestions:

1. You could build the regexes from something else; e.g. build them by expanding a simple template.
2. You could see if there is a better way of going the matching that doesn't involve regexes.